# How to remove Firebase Cloud Messaging Token in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter

When One user A log In and then Log out.
Then user B logs In. 
The notification intended for user A is received bu user B because the token generated for user A is not removed.
The dart package have no options for removing this token.

Answer (score 13):

Note from [Official documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#messaging):

> DEPRECATED: deleteInstanceID() has been deprecated in favor of
> deleteToken()

So to make current token invalid just add this code to your logout function:

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.deleteToken();
```

After that, messages sent by the server to this token will fail.

Answer (score 11):

EDIT: looks like `deleteInstanceID` was deprecated in favor of `deleteToken`. Please look the other answer for more info.

---

You can accomplish that by calling `deleteInstanceID`. Be aware that `deleteInstanceID` automatically recreates the token, so you have to `setAutoInitEnabled` to false beforehand. You can check the current auto-init value by querying `autoInitEnabled`.

Note: requires `firebase_messaging` version 2.1.0 or greater.