# Stop receiving push notifications in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am working on a flutter project where I need to stop receiving the push notifications when the user log out from the app but I am still receiving the notifications on the application. Any idea how to achieve it? (I am using an API for saving the device token to the server.)

Comment: You can use another api to, delete the token from the server & re-register on next sign in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when logging out delete the token on logging in refresh the token and save this to your server

this link can help you for deleting fcm tokens

[How to remove Firebase Cloud Messaging Token in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097924/how-to-remove-firebase-cloud-messaging-token-in-flutter/53104379)

Comment: thanks ... I used the same way for my problem.